# Go receiver implicit pointer conversion not working

Tags: go

I'm learning Go, and I was following the go tour.

In the exercise about Stringer, [here](http://tour.golang.org/methods/18), Implementing the function with a *IPAddr receiver doesn't seem to work, which the go tour describes as should work.

```
package main

import "fmt"

type IPAddr [4]byte

// TODO: Add a "String() string" method to IPAddr.
func (ip *IPAddr) String() string {
    return fmt.Sprintf("%v.%v.%v.%v", ip[0], ip[1], ip[2], ip[3])
}
func main() {
    hosts := map[string]IPAddr{
        "loopback":  {127, 0, 0, 1},
        "googleDNS": {8, 8, 8, 8},
    }
    for name, ip := range hosts {
        fmt.Printf("%v: %v\n", name, ip)
    }
}
```

Output is:

```
loopback: [127 0 0 1]
googleDNS: [8 8 8 8]
```

But changing `String() string` to `func (ip IPAddr)` from `func (ip *IPAddr)` gives the correct output:

```
loopback: 127.0.0.1
googleDNS: 8.8.8.8
```

Why is that?

Comment: Where does the go tour say that this should work with `*IPAddr` receiver?

Comment: Right [here](http://tour.golang.org/methods/6) and [here](http://tour.golang.org/methods/7)

Comment: note that a function with a receiver is **not** the same as method receiver

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The implicit conversion means that you can call the function on either a value, or pointer, but it does not satisfy the implementation of an interface. If you implement an interface with a pointer receiver, the pointer must be used in the function call.

The code below shows the `*IPAddr` used with the Stringer interface, and an `IPAddr` used with the new `foo()` function (also implemented with a pointer receiver):

```
package main

import "fmt"

type IPAddr [4]byte

// TODO: Add a "String() string" method to IPAddr.
func (ip *IPAddr) String() string {
    return fmt.Sprintf("%v.%v.%v.%v", ip[0], ip[1], ip[2], ip[3])
}

func (ip *IPAddr) foo() string {
    return "bar"
}

func main() {
    hosts := map[string]IPAddr{
        "loopback":  {127, 0, 0, 1},
        "googleDNS": {8, 8, 8, 8},
    }
    for name, ip := range hosts {
        fmt.Printf("%v: %v\n", name, &ip)

    fmt.Println(ip.foo())
    }
}
```

Comment: To further explain - in order to satisfy an interface in Go, a type must explicitly implement all of the interface functions. `Type` and `*Type` are fundamentally different things (which may need to handle the interface function in different ways). Go does some handy magic that lets you call functions on a `Type` even if they have a `*Type` receiver - but that does not _explicitly_ implement the interface..

Answer (score 3):

Implementing `func (ip IPAddr) String()` will work for both `IPAddr` and `*IPAddr` types.

Implementing `func (ip *IPAddr) String` will only work for `*IPAddr`.

Comment: I don't think this is correct, could you please elaborate?